# AJAX Uploaded image with resize

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file

i want to upload file using ajax but before i upload the image must be resize before submiting

so i get 2 main function

1 function is for resize image and other to handle the submit form 
but when the form submit my $_FILE is empty array in my ajax i already using new formData()

please check my resize end form code 
[this my form code](https://github.com/farhanrahmadi/web_alke/blob/master/application/views/cms_product.php)

and this is my form [handler](https://github.com/farhanrahmadi/web_alke/blob/master/assets/js/xiliari.js) on xSubmitForm

and will good to inform me why this happen thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its may bad i dont get the name on the file input